# How to show the health of a docker container in IntelliJ?

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose, health-monitoring

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file and I'm using IntellJ **2019.2** to run the service and it's working fine.

I would like to see the health status of my container (starting, healthy .etc) via IntelliJ.
However the only way I found, is `right-click on the container > inspect > search the state in the json`, which is not very handy.

Does anyone know another way to easily show the container health status ?

*The json from the inspection*:

```
[...]
"State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Health": {
          "Status": "healthy", // that's what I want
[...]
```

*The docker-compose file*:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  application:
    image: com.my.company/image
    depends_on: 
      - database
    build: ./build
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - app_network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-sSf", "http://localhost:8080/app"]
      start_period: 30s
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature request to show health status:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-214513

Comment: Well, the feature request is inactive, I don't think that we'll see it. But the author said `What happens instead? They look the same, but mouseover shows "unhealthy" status` - I didn't know about the mouseover, it's still better than my previous method

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to execute following command in terminal (OS or IntelliJ IDEA):

```
docker ps --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.RunningFor}}\t{{.Status}}"
```

Here just added some formatting, probably

```
docker ps -a
```

would be more than enough.

Comment: Thanks but I know about the cli but I'm looking for a built-in feature in the IDE.